# Axios Bad Request 400 Post

Tags: javascript, axios

```
const headers = {
    Authorization: 'Bearer fui3h73bjflkbf-hdug37o8' 
}
const body = { "name": "example.com", "account": { "id": "72672yhhuo2nu2" }, "jump_start": true, "type": "full" }


let url = 'https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones'
axios.post( 
    url,
    body,
    headers
  ).then(console.log).catch(console.log);
```

Can any help me with this? I keep getting a 400 bad request from Axios - I can pass that same token over a GET request and confirm its working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was formatting

```
var config = {
    headers: {'Authorization': "Bearer fui3h73bjflkbf-hdug37o8"}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you use to check the response? Here is the body of request:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": 6003,
            "message": "Invalid request headers",
            "error_chain": [
                {
                    "code": 6111,
                    "message": "Invalid format for Authorization header"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "messages": [],
    "result": null
}
```

So the problem is that you send wrong token. Check if it is correct.
You may use this one "Bearer YQSn-xWAQiiEh9qM58wZNnyQS7FUdoqGIUAbrh7T" from cloudflare site to check if you will get 403 Forbidden instead of your current 400. If so, your request is fine, and you just need correct token.

Comment: so that returns a 403 i assume because I am also using the wrong account ID to post with

Comment: absolutely! but it also means that you code works fine. So the only problem is uncorrect token 'Bearer fui3h73bjflkbf-hdug37o8'

Comment: so what's strange, I can throw the same info into postman and it works great. Have confirmed permissions on the token per the API guide. I keep thinking I am somehow passing the authorization in a format that they are not expecting